# How to get all video posts by specific user id

Tags: php, wordpress

I need videos posted by any specific user.

I have used the following code but it is still showing all the posts

```
$args = array ( 'post_author' => $id, 'post_type' => 'videos', 'posts_per_page' => 100,); 
$posts_array = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Have you done a print of `$id` to ensure you have the right value, as searching a blank value in post_author would presumably mean all authors, also have you created the custom post type videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) like this.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'author=' . $id . '&post_type=video&posts_per_page=100');

while($query->have_posts()) { 
   the_post();

   // Do you magic here
}
```

Comment: i found a solution, all i had to do is change post_author to just author

thank you all for your time and help